# How can I make verbatim's → use a monospace font

Tags: unicode, verbatim

I want to show UTF-8 characters representing a map like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}
\begin{verbatim}
# # # # # ↓ # # # # # # # #   # # #   
#         → → ↓                   #   
#           # ↓     #             #   
#           # → ↓   #             #   
#   # # # # #   ↓         # # # # #   
#             ↓ ←       #         #   
#             ↓         #         #   
#             ↓ # # # # #         #   
#             → → → → → → → ↓     #   
# # # #             #       → ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#         #         #         ↓   #   
#         #         # # # # # → → #   
#         #         #       #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
# # # # # # # # # # # #   # # # # #   

\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the arrows are too long so they don't match:
[image: Resulting document]

How can I make the arrows take the same space as the number signs?

Comment: Can you switch to lualatex or xelatex?

Comment: @Ulrike Indeed, that just solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's happening in your above file is that `→` is defined as `\rightarrow`, which in turn is defined as a specific (non-monospaced) character.

Instead, with XeTeX or LuaTeX you can use any Unicode characters you like, provided you're using a font that covers those characters. In this case, looking on my system for a monospaced font that covers all the characters mentioned (`# ↓ → ← ■ ╚ ╝`), I find a number of options (click on image to view it properly):

[image: options]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
whatever `verbatim` uses by default
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{Andale Mono}
\begin{verbatim}
Andale Mono
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{Courier New}
\begin{verbatim}
Courier New
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{Consolas}
\begin{verbatim}
Consolas
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{Lucida Console}
\begin{verbatim}
Lucida Console
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{Menlo}
\begin{verbatim}
Menlo
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}

\setmonofont{Times New Roman}
\begin{verbatim}
Times New Roman (not a monospace font!)
######
■╚↓→←╝
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

My preference would be to use an appropriate monospace font, rather than an image.

Comment: Compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`! Can't believe I didn't say that explicitly in the answer :-) Just noticed this answer again now as it got its first upvote.

Answer (score 4):

Using `textcomp` is sufficient.

1. Avoid `utf8x` that's been unmaintained for several years, whereas `utf8` is well maintained and has been extended to cover several character blocks.
2. Use the `T1` output encoding when writing Spanish.
3. The `es-noquoting` option is better than deactivating `<` and `>` as shorthands.

Now the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % needed for Spanish
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
# # # # # ↓ # # # # # # # #   # # #   
#         → → ↓                   #   
#           # ↓     #             #   
#           # → ↓   #             #   
#   # # # # #   ↓         # # # # #   
#             ↓ ←       #         #   
#             ↓         #         #   
#             ↓ # # # # #         #   
#             → → → → → → → ↓     #   
# # # #             #       → ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#         #         #         ↓   #   
#         #         # # # # # → → #   
#         #         #       #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
# # # # # # # # # # # #   # # # # #   
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `pmboxdraw` for the other symbols, provided you use the right ones. Short example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % needed for Spanish
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\pmboxdrawsetup{
  Block/box={\texttt{0}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
█ █ █ █ █ ↓ █ █ █ █ █ █ █ █   █ █ █
█         └ → ┐                   █
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is probably the cleanest. However, even though it was not part of the original question, it can't handle other special characters like ■  ╚ and ╝which I'd use in a better version of the same maps.

Comment: @MJGalram I just added some guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Works in pdflatex.  Inside a group, I invoke `\verbarrows` prior to the `verbatim`, which redefines `\leftarrow` and `\rightarrow` to fit in the space of an `X`.  When encountered inside the verbatim environment, the arrows will fit to the size of a `\ttfamily X`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\let\svrightarrow\rightarrow
\let\svleftarrow\rightarrow
\def\verbarrows{%
  \def\rightarrow{\setbox0=\hbox{X}\makebox[\wd0]{$\svrightarrow$}}%
  \def\leftarrow{\setbox0=\hbox{X}\makebox[\wd0]{$\svleftarrow$}}%
}
\begin{document}\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}
\bgroup\verbarrows%
\begin{verbatim}
# # # # # ↓ # # # # # # # #   # # #   
#         → → ↓                   #   
#           # ↓     #             #   
#           # → ↓   #             #   
#   # # # # #   ↓         # # # # #   
#             ↓ ←       #         #   
#             ↓         #         #   
#             ↓ # # # # #         #   
#             → → → → → → → ↓     #   
# # # #             #       → ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#         #         #         ↓   #   
#         #         # # # # # → → #   
#         #         #       #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
# # # # # # # # # # # #   # # # # #   
\end{verbatim}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Switching to the `verbatimbox` package can simplify the invocation and make it more versatile:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\let\svrightarrow\rightarrow
\let\svleftarrow\rightarrow
\def\verbarrows{%
  \def\rightarrow{\setbox0=\hbox{X}\makebox[\wd0]{$\svrightarrow$}}%
  \def\leftarrow{\setbox0=\hbox{X}\makebox[\wd0]{$\svleftarrow$}}%
}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}\shorthandoff{>}\shorthandoff{<}
\begin{verbnobox}[\verbarrows]
# # # # # ↓ # # # # # # # #   # # #   
#         → → ↓                   #   
#           # ↓     #             #   
#           # → ↓   #             #   
#   # # # # #   ↓         # # # # #   
#             ↓ ←       #         #   
#             ↓         #         #   
#             ↓ # # # # #         #   
#             → → → → → → → ↓     #   
# # # #             #       → ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#         #         #         ↓   #   
#         #         # # # # # → → #   
#         #         #       #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
# # # # # # # # # # # #   # # # # #   
\end{verbnobox}
\begin{verbnobox}[\tiny\verbarrows]
# # # # # ↓ # # # # # # # #   # # #   
#         → → ↓                   #   
#           # ↓     #             #   
#           # → ↓   #             #   
#   # # # # #   ↓         # # # # #   
#             ↓ ←       #         #   
#             ↓         #         #   
#             ↓ # # # # #         #   
#             → → → → → → → ↓     #   
# # # #             #       → ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#                   #       # ↓   #   
#         #         #         ↓   #   
#         #         # # # # # → → #   
#         #         #       #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
#         #                 #     #   
# # # # # # # # # # # #   # # # # #   
\end{verbnobox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As @Ulrike said, using lualatex or xelatex solves the issue in this particular instance. However, if you want to use unicode characters other the arrows you may find trouble. I certainly did, gave up and used images.

Comment: IMO one of the main attractions of using XeTeX or LuaTeX is to freely use arbitrary Unicode characters, so your experience is unfortunate. You just have to pick an appropriate font with `\setmonofont`; that's better than using images IMO. I just posted [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404096/48) to illustrate.